# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when installing tensor flow on Ubuntu 16.04.03

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow with cuda and gpu support. When I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/srivishnu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this error occurs when I type this command in:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Can you please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost always a missing path in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Find `libcublas.so.9.0` on your system (start looking under `/usr/local`).

If you don't find it, then install the CUDA 9.0 Toolkit (note that with TF 1.5 you want 9.0 and not 9.1, a common gotcha, at least common in-so-far as I made that mistake myself).

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

If you have it, then update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the appropriate `lib` directory.

If you've done either of those and are now getting a similar looking error for a cudnn related library, then repeat that process for the CUDNN library.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

I think the latest version works. Tensorflow depends on both CUDA toolkit and the CuDNN library extension.

Note that you can install all of this in userspace too (sudo is typical, but not required).

Comment: How do you update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the proper `lib`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable

Answer (score 1):

I had `cuda-9.0` installed and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was pointing to the correct location. Turned out that the permission of the folder `/usr/local/cuda-9.0` was wrong. I could not even `cd` to the folder. I changed the owner of the `cuda-9.0` from `root` to `my-user-name` and after that python was able to find the missing library.

Answer (score 1):

To easily find the `libcublas` file, run

```
sudo find / -iname 'libcublas*'
```

or

```
sudo locate libcublas
```

Then add the path to the folder containing that file into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Better still (and faster) is use:   locate libcublas