# Supervisor can't load Cuda libs , PATH IS NOT MISSING, works without supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow, supervisord

I've a python application with Flask, tensorflow-gpu ..., that runs without a problem when I run:

```
gunicorn server:app -b localhost:8000
```

but when I run it with the supervisor, it gives me the error

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not using virtualenv.

here is my supervisor config

```
[program:appserver]
command = gunicorn server:app -b localhost:8000
directory = /storage/appserver
user = root
stdout_logfile = /home/deploy/appserver/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/deploy/appserver/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stderr.log
redirect_stderr = True
```

What am I doing wrong?

If the app runs directly at the command line, why supervisor can't run it?

I've the env vars at the bashrc, like I said, it works if I run from the command line...

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/


root@xxxxx:/home/xxxxx# echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
root@xxxxxx:/home/xxxxx# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when installing tensor flow on Ubuntu 16.04.03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115391/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d)

Comment: A second reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499370/libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-while-running-tensorflow-in-ubu/49499804#49499804

Comment: No its not this, the path is not missing, as posted on the main post

Comment: Can you `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I'm still suspicious, you've got a rather complex statement in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that makes me think that a typo-like error might be occurring.

Comment: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor don't load environment variables, it doesn't depend on bash, so you must load environment variables in supervisor configuration directly.

Here my configuration as example:

```
[program:hoot_api_ml]

user           = hoot
environment    = LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
directory      = /home/hoot/backend/hoot/ml
command        = gunicorn3 -c ../../conf/api_ml/gunicorn.py api:APP

autostart      = true
autorestart    = true

stderr_logfile = /var/log/hoot/api_ml_supervisor.err
stdout_logfile = /var/log/hoot/api_ml_supervisor.log

stopsignal     = INT
```