# Tensorflow Will Not Import Due to libcublas Issue

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

I am working on setting up a local dev environment for Deep Learning. I was following the instructions in the first post on this thread on the Fast.ai forum:

http://forums.fast.ai/t/py3-and-tensorflow-setup/1460

Running `pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git` seems to have successfully installed Keras, but with some warnings.

```
Successfully built Keras
distributed 1.221.8 require msgpack, which is not installed.
tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement bleach==1.50, but you'll have to bleach 2.1.3 which is incompatible
Tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement html5lib--0.9999999, but youll have html5lib 1.0.1 which is incompatible.
…
Successfully installed Keras-2.1.6
```

When I try to import tensorflow, from iPython I get the following stack trace:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
     26 from tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/usrname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

My system is running Ubuntu 16.04 with a GTX 1060 GPU.

Update: I made the changes to my `~/.bashrc` file. So that my LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the location of lib64, which on my system resides at:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Saved the file, then restarted the system and once again tried to import tensorflow from inside iPython. Once again I get an error message containing:

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I run nvidia-smi, the result is :

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  8%   54C    P0    26W / 120W |    318MiB /  6075MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1017      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           159MiB |
|    0      1826      G   compiz                                       156MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I run apt-update, nvidia, which is the last segment to run returns the following:

```
Ign:23 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:24 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release
Get:25 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:25 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg
Fetched 393 kB in 2min 0s (3,266 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
W: The repository 'http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Seems like the public keys are part of the issue. I have tried running the following command:

sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

The results is:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.GlsZMuriaF/gpg.1.sh --fetch-keys
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: WARNING: unable to fetch URI http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub: keyserver error
ub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499370/libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-while-running-tensorflow-in-ubu/49499804#49499804

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115391/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d/49121818#49121818

Comment: @DavidParks thank you for your response. I attempted the first of two steps suggested in your second link, with regard to the ~/.bashrc file. I have updated my post with the new information.

Comment: Can you run `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and verify that the exact file `libcublas.so.9.0` lives in one of the directories listed there? I'm 99% sure this is just a path issue. it's really easy for little errors to creep into the process.

Comment: @DavidParks the result of echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH was /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64

Comment: The actual path on my machine is /usr/local/cuda/lib64. Just updated ~/.bashrc and restarted my system. The result is the same error.

Comment: It sure sounds right. You don't need a reboot or anything, simply setting the environment variable is enough (for testing you can just manipulate the local shell environment variable, then update `.bashrc` once it works. It certainly sounds like you have everything correct. You have CUDA 9.0, not 9.1, good, and your path sounds correct, and it looks like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly. I can't think of any other cause for this.

Comment: @DavidParks Just looked in the lib64 file and realized it does not contain a libcublas.so.9.0 file. Or any file that begins libcublas. The only files it contains are: libcudnn.so; libcudnn.so9.5; libcudn.so.5.1.10 and libcudnn_static.a

Comment: That is the problem then. Do a search for `libcublas.so.9.0` and see if it's somewhere else. If not I'd question the installation. It should have come along with the CUDA installation I expect.

Comment: If you found files with `libcudnn` you're probably pointing to the CuDNN libraries, which are necessary, but you *also* need the Cuda libraries. There are generally 2 paths you need on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, one pointing to the cuda libraries and the other pointing to the additional CUDNN libraries (which are a separate install).

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed in this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15604) in detail. The following worked for me:

1. Download the Cuda 9.0 from [Nvida archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal)
2. Installation Instructions:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install cuda
   ```
3. Update the paths

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
   ```